# Как правильно испльзовать ретроспективную проверку для исключения из совпадений в регулярных выражениях?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

По задумке, данное регулярное выражение НЕ должно захватывать html-тэг, если перед ним на предудыщей строке стоит комментарий `keepSrc`.

```
^(?!\s*<!--\s+keepSrc\s+-->\s*(?:\r\n|\r|\n))^\s*<img.+?src="(.+?)".*\/?>\s*?$
```

Должно войти в совпадения:

```html
<img title="testTitle" src="images/example" alt="">
```

Не должно войти в совпадения:

```html
<!-- keepSrc -->
<img src="images/HeroImage.png" alt="">
```

На данный момент у меня в массив совпадений попадают оба `img`. Какую ошибку я допустил?

Comment: У меня не захватывает вторую (экранировал `"`). https://regex101.com/r/1WYotu/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что вместо вперёд смотрящей вам нужно использовать назад смотрящую проверку:

```
~(?<!<!--\skeepSrc\s-->)\s+\K<img[^>]+src="(.+?)"[^>]*>~s
```

[Демо PHP](https://regex101.com/r/1WYotu/3)

---

> *а в JavaScript вместо \K что можно использовать?*

Опережающую или ретроспективную проверки:

```
/(?<!<!--\skeepSrc\s-->\s+)<img[^>]+src="(.+?)"[^>]*>/gm
```

[Демо JS](https://regex101.com/r/1WYotu/4)

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Скажите, а в JavaScript вместо \K что можно использовать?